# 2D R2C FFT as 1D FFT using FFTW

Tags: c, signal-processing, fft, fftw

For various reasons, I need to do a 2D FFT transform (both forward and then inverse) of real data input as a 1D transform. I use the excellent FFTW library.

Algorithm should be simple, first I do a 1D R2C transform of every row, then of every resulting column. For this, I use advanced interface of FFTW:

```
int N = ...; int M = ...; int M2 = M / 2 + 1;
r_array = ... // fftw_malloc'd as NxM array of doubles
c_array = ... // fftw_malloc'd as NxM2 array of fftw_complex

int rank = 1;
int nfr[] = {M}; int nfr2[] = {M2};    
int howmany = N;
int idist = M; int odist = M2;
int istride = 1; int ostride = 1;
int *inembed = nfr, *onembed = nfr2;

plan_forward_row = fftw_plan_many_dft_r2c(rank, nfr, howmany, r_array, inembed, istride, idist,  c_array, onembed, ostride, odist, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
fftw_execute(plan_forward_row);

//do something else...

int nfc[] = {N};
howmany = M2;
idist = 1; odist = 1;
istride = N, ostride = N;
inembed = nfc, onembed = nfc;

plan_forward_col = fftw_plan_many_dft(rank, nfc, howmany, c_array, inembed, istride, idist,  c_array, onembed, ostride, odist, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
fftw_execute(plan_forward_col);

//do something else...

//now inverse (backward)...
int nbc[] = {N};
howmany = M2;
idist = 1; odist = 1;
istride = N; ostride = N;
inembed = nbc; onembed = nbc;

plan_backward_col = fftw_plan_many_dft(rank, nbc, howmany, c_array, inembed, istride, idist,  c_array, onembed, ostride, odist, FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
fftw_execute(plan_backward_col);

//do something else...

int nbr[] = {M2}; int nbr2[] = {M};    
howmany = Nx;
idist = M2; odist = M;
istride = 1, ostride = 1;
inembed = nbr, onembed = nbr2;

plan_backward_row = fftw_plan_many_dft_c2r(rank, nbr, howmany, c_array, inembed, istride, idist,  r_array, onembed, ostride, odist, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
fftw_execute(plan_backward_row);
```

However, the result is not correct. Is the problem in the fact that R2C output is only the non redundant array of complex numbers, or did I make a mistake in using advanced interface?

Comment: I have found the error, in last transform, value of `nbr` should be just `M`, not `M2`. Also, all `nembed` parameters can be `NULL`, it is not necessary to use them in this example.

Comment: i am impressed: your title is literally 75% acronym.

Answer (score 0):

The basic FFT algorithm is complex->complex. With this part you may divide an 2d FFT in a sequence of two 1d FFTs.

The usual FFT Interfaces do a lot of optimization:

1. pack real input into a complex array
2. do the complex->complex FFT
3. remove redundant parts

It is part (2) which you need to call for your rows, then columns.

Comment: That would be slower, and defeats the whole purpose of R2C transform.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you call the 2D version of FFTW directly?

See the function `fftw_plan_dft_r2c_2d()` in

http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Multi_002dDimensional-DFTs-of-Real-Data.html#Multi_002dDimensional-DFTs-of-Real-Data

Comment: 2d works the way I needed it, however, like I said, I needed it as 2x1d. Anyways, I solved the problem long ago, the problem was one of the parameters of the advanced interface, I don't remember which in this example.